# Where to look to get started with making an animated clock with Swing in Java?

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am trying to make an animated clock using Swing in Java. The picture I have posted is a basic idea of what I am looking for. In the end I hope to have the arrow be stationary and the numbers move to indicate the hour, plus I want to have a nested circle with 60 boxes doing the same. I'm not looking for code on how to do this just some tips on how I should get started, links to good tutorials, that kind of thing. Thanks.

---

[image: clock]

---

**edit:** I for got to mention that I'm not actually making a clock, its just the simplest way to explain the premise of what I'm trying to accomplish, to the more general the answers the better.

Comment: Did you consider using JavaFX? www.javafx.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could draw it on a [JPanel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) by overriding the [`paintComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#printComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method.

Use a [Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to tick every second to redraw the clock. The timer fires ActionEvents which your panel could listen for.

As for drawing, the center of the boxes with the numbers can be calculated with a bit of trigonometry. For the hour boxes: `x = sin(hour / 12 * 2 * pi)` and `y = cos(hour / 12 * 2 * pi)`. For the minute boxes: `x = sin(minute / 60 * 2 * pi)` and `y = cos(minute / 60 * 2 * pi)`. These will be relative to the center of the clock and will need to be multiplied by some constant. Actually, those equations might not be quite right, but the way to do it is something like that.

Answer (score 2):

This page on [Java 2D](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp) looks like it might be a good place to start. Disclaimer: I've never seriously dealt with Java graphics before.

Answer (score 1):

I found some code in this [posting](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=31&threadID=5385409&start=5) which I believe is actually fairly close to what you want. It shows how to draw multiple sprites in a circle about a given point. It even does animation at 1/10 of a second. Slow it down to 60 minutes and its close to what you want.

Note, the code doesn't compile as posted. Just comments out the 2 statements in error and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jhlabs.com/java/layout/index.html

provides a ClockLayout layoutmanager